# when compiling, conf/routes still refers to old path

Tags: github, playframework

First I had local repository for https://github.com/tenzan/pfj_ch03.git.

1. Then I made a copy of the whole folder and renamed to pfj_ch05
2. `cd pfj_ch05/`
3. `play ~run`

On the browser localhost:9000 I'm having error, which refers to In /Users/askar/work/playforjava/work/**pfj_ch03**/conf/routes at line 10 as in picture.
[image]

For some reason it stil refers to **pfj_ch03** instead of **pfj_ch05**.

You can refer to https://github.com/tenzan/pfj_ch05.git for pfj_ch05 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute `play clean` and try again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MartinGrotzke, thanks! Now it's not referring to the old path, though it's giving another error which is not related to this topic.

Comment: @HinataHyuga I think the missing clean was causing the issue, so IMHO this *is* the answer. Or did I get anything wrong? oscar: what's the new issue, have you asked it separately?